# UIPopoverController inRect issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, rect

I have a UIViewController that contains a UIView subclass as a subview. In the subview, I dynamically create another UIView. When the innermost view is created then the UIViewController is informed via a delegation that it must show a UIPopovercontroller whose arrow head need to be pointing to the inner most view. In the delegate method call, I also pass the origin of the inner most view so that the UIViewcontroller make use of this CGPoint to create the popover controller. The problem is that the UIPopovercontroller is not being positioned at the desired location.

```
MyController* myController = [ [ MyController alloc] init]; 
UINavigationController *aNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]                    initWithRootViewController: myController];
self.popOver = [[[UIPopoverController alloc]
                initWithContentViewController:aNavController] autorelease];
[aNavController release];

CGRect rect;
//CGPoint p = CGPointMake(currentPage.frame.size.width/2, currentPage.frame.size.height/2); 
rect.origin = point;    //here point is the origin of the inner most view
rect.size = self.view.frame.size;
[self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect: rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

What I am missing in this code that is forcing the popover to appear deviated from the position instead of at the desired place.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your are not passing the correct view to your popOver, check once ...

```
[self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect: rect inView:myInnerView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: @Parvez:  please go through  the UIPopOvercontroller        http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial       http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775        try to understand how r they using it in sample code ...

Answer (score 0):

The `rect` you are presenting your popover from may be too large.

You have it set to the size of the entire view instead of the size of your inner most view.